# Angularjs file upload with defer

Tags: angularjs

I am using https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/README.md

I need to upload an image and then do something on the current scope.

```
var some_var;

uploader.uploadItem(0).then(function(result){ 
  // use result here    
})
```

So it there a way to do it or do I have to create my own service that will encapsulate the promise deferred pattern ?

Comment: Check out the events section in the README you linked.

Answer (score 0):

```
uploader.bind('success', function(event, xhr, item, response) {
  // do stuff
});
```

or

```
uploader.bind('complete', function(event, xhr, item, response) {
  // do stuff
});
```

[Events section of README](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload#events).

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't help me. It's not clear and I am not sure I can use it since the // do stuff section uses data from another ajax call, I want to call the uploader on another success call back.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the `onSuccessItem` callback function like so:

```
uploader.onSuccessItem = function () {
    console.log('item uploaded successfully');
};
```

You can see the [list of callbacks here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#callbacks). Other callbacks include  `onErrorItem`, `onCancelItem`, `onCompleteAll`, etc.